# How to make a batch file execute a reg file

Tags: windows, file, batch-file, registry, elevated-privileges

I have the following code

```
@echo off
file.reg
pause
```

This works but when the batch file is elevated I get an error saying that it cannot find the file. does any one know what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
 @echo off
 rem  set __COMPAT_LAYER=RunAsInvoker  
 REGEDIT.EXE  /S  "%~dp0\file.reg"
 pause
```

Try this

If you are accessing locations in the registry that does not require admin privileges you can use `__COMPAT_LAYER` environment variable.Just execute this before using regedit:

```
set __COMPAT_LAYER=RunAsInvoker
```

that will prevent UAC pop-up if your script is not ran as administrator.

Answer (score 10):

Probably, starting batch with elevated privileges will change starting directory to `%windir%\system32` (path where `cmd.exe` is located).

Use:

```
"%~dp0\file.reg"
```

to always execute `file.reg` located in same directory as batch file.

Also consider using `REG` command, as it allows you to perform console operations on registry (check `REG /?`).

Comment: when it comes to loading a `.reg` file I prefer a `REGEDIT /S` to surpass the pop-up.`REG` is a pretty good idea when you have no admin privileges as it checks permissions per registry key , but unfortunately is not available on all windows systems (home editions in particular).But +1